# Facebook Pixel is not working on Shopify website

Tags: shopify, facebook-pixel

I have tried both by adding in Shopify Pixel setting and by adding by manually pasting code in theme.liquid but pixel is still showing error.

Error message :-
"We detected event code but the pixel has not activated for this event, so no information was sent to Facebook. This could be due to an error in the code, but could also occur if the pixel fires on a dynamic event such as a button click"

I am preety exausted finding th solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your Facebook pixel is not activated. Just Goto Facebook and try to activate it.

Once activated then edit your pixel fire code and add init into the facebook pixel before tracking code. like below..

```
fbq("init", FACEBOOK_PIXEL);
```

You can share your code here if still you are stuck, I'll help you out.